# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: name must be an instance of basestring

Tags: django, mongodb, django-nonrel, django-mongodb-engine

I am trying to use `Mongodb` with in my `Django`.

Below there are connection settings in `settings.py`

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)


MANAGERS = ADMINS



DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine', 
        'NAME': '',                      
        'USER': '',                      
        'PASSWORD': '',                  
        'HOST': 'localhost',                      
        'PORT': 27017,                      
    }
}
```

when I am trying to run `python manage.py syncdb` I am getting an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/sakeer/workspace/entevirtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 429, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/sakeer/workspace/entevirtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/sakeer/workspace/entevirtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/sakeer/workspace/entevirtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/sakeer/workspace/entevirtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/home/sakeer/workspace/entevirtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 59, in handle_noargs
    tables = connection.introspection.table_names()
  File "/home/sakeer/workspace/entevirtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_mongodb_engine-0.4.0-py2.7.egg/django_mongodb_engine/base.py", line 76, in table_names
  File "/home/sakeer/workspace/entevirtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_mongodb_engine-0.4.0-py2.7.egg/django_mongodb_engine/base.py", line 106, in __getattr__
  File "/home/sakeer/workspace/entevirtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_mongodb_engine-0.4.0-py2.7.egg/django_mongodb_engine/base.py", line 133, in _connect
  File "/home/sakeer/workspace/entevirtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo-2.4.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1025, in __getitem__
  File "/home/sakeer/workspace/entevirtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo-2.4.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1014, in __getattr__
  File "/home/sakeer/workspace/entevirtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo-2.4.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pymongo/database.py", line 74, in __init__

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: name must be an instance of basestring
```

i am using django 1.3

thanks in advance

Comment: you have no database define

Comment: Why do you even bother with `syncdb` with Mongo? It will create collections on first access.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've never used mongodb with django, but I'll take a stab just by following the trace. You need to add a value to the `NAME` setting in your DB configuration

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine', 
        'NAME': 'foobar',                      
        'USER': '',                      
        'PASSWORD': '',                  
        'HOST': 'localhost',                      
        'PORT': 27017,                      
    }
}
```

The error is being thrown [here in `pymongo`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/pymongo/database.py#L60) which is created [around here via `django_mongo_engine`](https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine/blob/master/django_mongodb_engine/base.py#L133)